# Send to facebook proxy email addresses

Tags: facebook, email

is it possible to send to a facebook proxy email address directly through gmail or yahoo? I changed the contact email under app settings to the email address I want to send from, but the emails just don't go through. Anything I'm doing wrong here, or do I need to use facebook api?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ramhound, are the facebook proxy email addresses completely useless then? Is there any other way through the api to send?

Comment: Wow, no one knows anything about facebook proxy emails?